# highcharts pie chart multiple sections selection

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to select multiple sections in pie chart. And section should be unselected on clicking, if it is already selected.

I found an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5SXX/3/). But in this case, only one section can be selected and selected ones get deselected on clicking on any other section.

Similarly, I found another example [

> $(function () {
>       var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
>           chart: {
>               renderTo: 'container',
>               type: 'pie'
>
> ```
>     },
>     plotOptions: {
>         series: {
>             states: {
>                 hover: {
>                     enabled: false
>                 }
>             },
>             point: {
>                 events: {
>                     click: function () {
>                         this.graphic.attr({
>                             fill: 'yellow'
>                         });
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     tooltip: {
>         enabled: false
>     },
>     series: [{
>         data: [{
>             name: 'test',
>             y: 29.9,
>             color: "#CCCCCC",
>             active: false
>         }, {
>             name: 'test2',
>             y: 71.5,
>             color: "#CCCCCC",
>             active: false
>         }, {
>             name: 'test3',
>             y: 106.4,
>             color: "#CCCCCC",
>             active: false
>         }]
>     }]
> }); });
> ```

][2](http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/8/). In this case multiple sections can be selected but they are not deselected on clicking again.

Please help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3zy8p/13/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(event){
                        this.slice(null);
                        this.select(null, true);
                        console.log(this.series.chart.getSelectedPoints());
                    }
                }  
            }                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works perfect. Thanks Pawel. Only thing remaining is - on every click I want to print id of all selected sections. Can you please suggest how can this be achieved.

Comment: So just print `this.series.chart.getSelectedPoints()` array which contains all selected points. In JS console you have reference..

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Can you please also explain how is the above answer working ? And even this link seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/3zy8p/12/ ... so how is your answer an improvement over this ?

Comment: IMPORTANT: And actually instead of slicing section out, I just want to change color to yellow to mark selection and change color back to original color to mark deselection. Not able to achieve this.

Comment: Both examples are mine, but if you want to get list of selected points then use `this.select()`. To change color just set `states.select.color`. If you don't want slice, set `slicedOffset: 0`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3zy8p/14/

Comment: You are a HighCharts ROCKSTAR !! And m even new to JS. Thanks a ton. Just one last thing. when we do getSelectedPoints(), I do not see a way to extract data values corresponding to selected section from the returned array. I am pretty sure this is something trivial and I am acting stupid.

Comment: Having said that I am still trying to understand how is the solution working. I know I have not understood it as I am having hard time to make small changes. Like instead of changing color to Red on click, how can be simply change the brightness of the existing color.

Comment: In returned array you have points. Open console (for example in chrome) and click on objects to see what properties you have. To set brightness you will need to set `states.select.color` for each points, sorry. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3zy8p/16/

Comment: Thanks Pawel for being so patient with me. :)   jsfiddle.net/3zy8p/16  seems to be broken.

Comment: Only first slice has set color (click Firefox). :)

Comment: Stupid me. I am facing a really weird error. I have a donut chart (pie chart with multiple series), your code does not work there. But if I put a wrong console.log, it works and logs error. When I say wrong, I mean console.log(this.series[0].chart.getSelectedPoints()); .. it logs an error serious[0] not found and everything works perfect. But if I change it to how it supposed to be or if I remove console statement all together, it does not work. :(

Comment: Sure: support@highcharts.com :) Anyway, you can't get selected points from specific series, only for a whole chart.

Comment: mails to supports@highcharts.com .go to you ? :O

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52610/discussion-between-user1744413-and-pawel-fus)

Comment: Can you please suggest how does this works "this.select(null, true);" .. what it is doing .. m tryying to understand so that I can get this working with a donut

Answer (score 1):

`Shift + Mouseclick` or `CTRL + Mouseclick` lets you select/deselect 'points'. Does the job by simply setting:

`allowPointSelect : true`

Comment: How to achieve this by default ? By Default I mean if some section is selected and user clicks on other section that section too get selected. And only way to deselect a section is by cicking on section itself.

Comment: I'm still checking this out, but this works on Windows as far as I know. Will report back later if I found more :)

Comment: I think I did not express myself clearly. What you suggested of course works. What I want is this: Every mouse click on pie chart should works as "ctrl+mouseclick"