# Highcharts pie chart list of selected section

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have enabled my pie chart to have multiple sections selected. (Not yet got it working as I want it though). Open SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613431/highcharts-pie-chart-multiple-sections-selection/23613547?noredirect=1#comment36251552_23613547)

But once I get this done, I would like to return the list of selected sections everytime a change in made in any selection.

Can someone please suggest. !!

My COde:

```
  series: [{
        name: 'Departments', 
        // allowPointSelect : true,
        slicedOffset: 0,
        states: {
           select: {
            color: 'red'    
        }
    },
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function(event){
                            //this.slice(null);
                            this.select(null, true);
                            filterCharts(cloneDonutData.Departments, dChart.series[0].name,this.name);
                            //console.log(this.series[0].chart.getSelectedPoints());
                        }
                    }  
                } ,
data: ....
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSelectedPoints

getSelectedPoints () Since 1.2.0

Returns an array of all currently selected points in the chart. Points can be selected either programmatically by the point.select() method or by clicking.

Comment: Hey Pawel, I am still not able to get this working. Sorry to bother you again. I am pasting the code here. So in the filterCharts method, I need to detect what all sections of pie are selected and update other charts on basis of that.  Please help !!

Comment: Can't you just pass as argument returned array of selected points from `getSelectedPoints()` method? Like this: `filterCharts(cloneDonutData.Departments, dChart.series[0].name,this.name,this.series[0].chart.getSelectedPoints());`

Comment: Doing that returns a mess, I am not able to extract required information from that .. which is nothing but the data.

Comment: Can't I simply iterate through series and see for which of them selected is set to true ? instead of using getSelectedPoints() .. as it is so confusing + my limited js knowledge + no working example online

Comment: Yes, you can iterate over points and check `selected` property, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.selected).